# Windows Store Slider Mouseover Background

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a slider in my Windows Store App that I have set the bar color to orange. My problem is, whenever the user mouses over the slider, the color changes to the default purple color. Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom `Style` for the Slider. The default `Style` is defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709929.aspx).

Just search in the `Style` for all references to the different purple colors and replace them with the orange colors you desire.

If you want this for just a single control, you can define it directly in the `Control`'s `XAML`. If you want it for all controls on a page, add it to the page's Resources and set the style of each control via a `StaticResource`. If you want this for all `Slider`s, add it to your `App.Xaml`'s `Resources` or one of your `MergedDictionaries` with no key defined (and `TargetType="Slider"`).